# display product is belongs to category in android listview using xml parsing

Tags: java, android, listview, xml-parsing

I have to pass the category,subcategory and product details through xml parsing in my android listview application.

```
This is my xml feed:

<Feed>
    <category>
        <Category>
            <Categoryname>Books</Categoryname>
            <SubCategory>
                <subcategoryname>Internet</subcategoryname>
                <Product>
                    <Name>New Masters of Flash</Name>
                    <Price>79.99</Price>
                </Product>
                <Product>
                    <Name>Professional Java Server Programming</Name>
                    <Price>63.99</Price>
                </Product>
            </SubCategory> 
            <SubCategory>
                <subcategoryname>Software</subcategoryname>
                <Product>
                    <Name>Krishnaveni</Name>
                    <Price>79.99</Price></Product>
                <Product>
                    <Name>Veeman</Name>
                    <Price>63.99</Price>
                </Product>
            </SubCategory>
        </Category>
    </category>
</Feed>
```

Here i have faced some problems.

I have to run the app means

---->  main activity have to displayed Books(Category) only.
---->  i have to click the Books listview means am getting the (SubCategory).
     They are:

```
Internet
Software
```

---->After i have to click **Internet** means am getting product of that particular(Internet) category.
They are:

```
New Masters of Flash
Professional Java Server Programming
```

If i have to click the 2nd subcategory(**Software**) means am i have to get the below results:

```
Krishnaveni
Veeman
```

Here only i have faced some problem.

Here i have to click internet subcategory means am getting 4 products.Same method is for software also.i have to click software subcategory means am getting 4 products.

How can i develop this.please help me.how can i get the product for that particular subcategory.

This is my coding part:

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends Activity {
static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168/xcart432pro/feed.xml";
 private static final int Tech = 0;

 static String KEY_CATEGORY = "Category";
 static final String KEY_TITLE = "Categoryname";

ListView lview3;
LazyAdapter adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_CATEGORY);

        // looping through all song nodes &lt;song&gt;
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);


            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));

            songsList.add(map);
        }
    lview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);
    lview3.setAdapter(adapter);

    lview3.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = songsList.get(position);
         switch (position)
         {
             case Tech:
                 Intent tech = new Intent(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.this, com.androidhive.xmlparsing.SubCate.class);
                 tech.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, "Books");
                 startActivity(tech);   
                 break;


             default:
                 break;
         }
        }  

     });
```

Second Activity:

```
public class SubCate extends Activity {
static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168/xcart432pro/feed.xml";
 private static final int Tech = 0;
 private static final int Sport =1;
 static String KEY_CATEGORY = "SubCategory";
 static  final String KEY_SUBCATE = "subcategoryname";
ListView lview3;
ListViewCustomAdapter adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_CATEGORY);

        // looping through all song nodes &lt;song&gt;
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key =&gt; value

            map.put(KEY_SUBCATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SUBCATE));

            songsList.add(map);
        }
    lview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(this, songsList);
    lview3.setAdapter(adapter);

    lview3.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = songsList.get(position);
         switch (position)
         {
             case Tech:
                 Intent tech = new Intent(SubCate.this, com.androidhive.xmlparsing.Catalogue.class);
                 tech.putExtra(KEY_SUBCATE, "Internet");
                 startActivity(tech);   
                 break;
             case Sport:
                 Intent sport = new Intent(SubCate.this, com.androidhive.xmlparsing.Catalogue.class);
                 sport.putExtra(KEY_SUBCATE, "Software");
                    startActivity(sport);   
                 break;


             default:
                 break;
         }
        }  

     });
```

Third Activity:

```
public class Catalogue extends Activity {

// static String URL = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/48258247/catalogue.json";
static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168/xcart432pro/feed.xml";

 static String KEY_CATEGORY = "Product";


 static final String KEY_TITLE = "Name";

static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
static final String KEY_COST = "Price"; 
//static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "Image";

ListView list;
ListAdapter adapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_CATEGORY);

        // looping through all song nodes &lt;song&gt;
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key =&gt; value

            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
           map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESCRIPTION));
            map.put(KEY_COST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
          //  map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new ListAdapter(this, songsList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        System.out.println("Category is:- " + KEY_CATEGORY);
        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = songsList.get(position);

            }

        });
```

please check the code and give me solution for this.please help me ya.

**EDIT:**

I have to add the code on my 2nd activity(SubCate.java)

first declare the KEY_TITLE

```
 static final String KEY_TITLE = "Categoryname";
```

after onCreate function added below line:

```
    Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
    KEY_CATEGORY = bdl.getString(KEY_TITLE);
```

I have added some code on 3rd activity(Catalogue.java) also.

first declare the KEY_SUBCATE:

```
static  final String KEY_SUBCATE = "subcategoryname";
```

after have to added below line after onCreate() function:

```
      Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
      KEY_CATEGORY = bdl.getString(KEY_SUBCATE);
```

Now i have to run the app means am doesn't get any products.please help me.how can i get the product on correct category.

Answer (score 0):

Just Make the `final` every product before clicking on sub Category . I think your problem will be solved.If you will not make these final values will be take last position every time.

I think you send product form here:---

```
      map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
       map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESCRIPTION));
        map.put(KEY_COST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
```

Just Replace of it:---

```
final  String key_title=parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE);
final String key_desc=parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESCRIPTION);
fiinal String key_cost=parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST);


    map.put(KEY_TITLE, key_title);
       map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, key_desc);
        map.put(KEY_COST, key_cost);
```

Comment: please explain detailly.which file and line i have to change here.

Comment: for example :-final int temp_veriable=ur_current_value;
then put temp_variable it will take value according ur position.

Comment: i have used final value only on every product.please check my code

Comment: @DeepankerChaudhary no ya.Now also am getting same output only